# Which API to use to add an OTH segment to a PNR

Tags: sabre

I would like to use the Sabre Webservices API to add an OTH segment to a PNR. Can anyone advise the correct API to use?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either MiscSegmentSellLLSRQ or PassengerDetailsRQ which orchestrates the before mentioned service.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/Sell_Miscellaneous_Segments

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Passenger_Details